# Kali linux is not booting up from virtual box

Tags: boot, virtualbox, kali-linux

I executed

```
$sudo apt-get update
$sudo apt upgrade -y
```

After that it took 3 hours to download some packages .After when download is complete then it was extracting those packages and installing on my system it was about 30% done then I had urgent work and had to close my virtual box. After that its not booting.When I start my virtual box and select kali-os and hit start it shows nothing just a black screen appears.

[image: kali-linux]

What has happened & why its not booting? How can I fix it?

Comment: I have seen that once or twice on a Kali Virtual Machine.  I have been able to restart the machine,  Ctrl-Alt-F1 to get a Terminal Login, then log in at the terminal prompt, sudo apt autoremove, then restart when done and it should work.

Comment: @John I cant log in the screen just displays login and blinks